# Count event occurrences per client based on multiple reference dates

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I am fairly new to R, and I have a data set with client numbers and the dates of a few thousand events. The data is formatted like this:

```
data <- data.frame("Client"=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2)), "Date"=as.Date(c("2015-11-20", "2015-12-04", "2016-01-08", "2016-04-07", "2015-12-19", "2016-02-02", "2016-02-21", "2016-01-04", "2016-02-12")), "Event"=rep(1, 9))
data
  Client       Date Event
1      1 2015-11-20     1
2      1 2015-12-04     1
3      1 2016-01-08     1
4      1 2016-04-07     1
5      2 2015-12-19     1
6      2 2016-02-02     1
7      2 2016-02-21     1
8      3 2016-01-04     1
9      3 2016-02-12     1
```

Given a set of reference dates,

```
 refdates <- as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-03-01"))
```

I would like to count the number of events per client that occurred (1) 30 days after the reference date, (2) 0-30 days before the reference date, and (3) 31-60 days before the reference date for the set of reference dates.

I want the output to be a data frame that looks like this:

```
  Client    RefDate post30 prior30 prior31.60
1      1 2016-01-01      1       1          1
2      1 2016-03-01      0       0          1
3      2 2016-01-01      0       1          0
4      2 2016-03-01      0       2          0
5      3 2016-01-01      1       0          0
6      3 2016-03-01      0       1          1
```

I feel like I should be able to do this using plyr, but I'm feeling a bit over my head.  Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R method.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(refdates, FUN=function(i) {
  aggregate(cbind("post30"=data$Date - i > -1 & data$Date - i < 31,
                  "prior30"=data$Date - i > -31 & data$Date - i < 0, 
                  "prior31.60"=data$Date - i > -61 & data$Date - i < -30),
            list(data$Client), FUN=sum)
}))
```

Here is a quick break down:

- The `aggregate` function sums the logical values that fall within a time window for each client for a specific reference date.
- `cbind` allows us to calculate multiple windows at one time as well as add names to the output.
- `lapply` runs through the reference dates and calls `aggregate`. This returns a list of what we are looking for.
- finally, `do.call` takes in this list of data.frames and `rbinds` them to create a single data.frame.

Comment: Similarly, to avoid multiple comparisons, `findInterval` can be handy; `do.call(rbind, lapply(refdates, function(d) do.call(rbind, tapply(cut(data$Date, d + c(-60, -30, 0, 30), labels = c("prior31.60", "prior30", "post30")), data$Client, table))))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @alexis_laz. I am aware of `findInterval`, but haven't had the insight/opportunity to use it yet. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  This is fantastic. I am again reminded how powerful and succinct the R language is.

Answer (score 1):

I used dplyr in my example.  You stated it's just a few thousand rows so provided the number of reference dates isn't too large, this shouldn't be too computationally intensive.

```
require(dplyr)

data <- data.frame("Client"=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2)), "Date"=as.Date(c("2015-11-20", "2015-12-04", "2016-01-08", "2016-04-07", "2015-12-19", "2016-02-02", "2016-02-21", "2016-01-04", "2016-02-12")), "Event"=rep(1, 9))
data

refdates <- as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-03-01"))

data %>%
  merge(refdates, all = T) %>%
  rename(RefDate = y) %>%
  mutate(
    post30 = ifelse(between(Date - RefDate, 1, 31), 1, 0),
    prior30 = ifelse(between(Date - RefDate, -30, 0), 1, 0),
    prior30.60 = ifelse(between(Date - RefDate, -60, -31), 1, 0)
         ) %>%
   group_by(Client, RefDate) %>%
   summarise(post30 = sum(post30),
            prior30 = sum(prior30),
            prior30.60 = sum(prior30.60)
  )
```

This yielded:

```
  Client    RefDate post30 prior30 prior30.60
   (dbl)     (date)  (dbl)   (dbl)      (dbl)
1      1 2016-01-01      1       1          1
2      1 2016-03-01      0       0          1
3      2 2016-01-01      0       1          0
4      2 2016-03-01      0       2          0
5      3 2016-01-01      1       0          0
6      3 2016-03-01      0       1          1
```

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt response.  Although I don't quite follow all of the steps, I look forward diving in to learn more!

Comment: No problem! If I can help explain anything, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>%
  merge(refdates) %>%
  rename(RefDate = y) %>%
  group_by(Client, RefDate) %>%
  mutate(Date.diff = Date - RefDate) %>%
  summarise(post30 = sum(Date.diff < 30 & Date.diff > 0),
            prior30 = sum(Date.diff < 0 & Date.diff > -30),
            prior31.60 = sum(Date.diff < -30 & Date.diff > -60))

out
  Client    RefDate post30 prior30 prior31.60
   (dbl)     (date)  (int)   (int)      (int)
1      1 2016-01-01      1       1          1
2      1 2016-03-01      0       0          1
3      2 2016-01-01      0       1          0
4      2 2016-03-01      0       2          0
5      3 2016-01-01      1       0          0
6      3 2016-03-01      0       1          1
```